# Python olefile to read text from PPT files

Tags: python

I'm just getting some binary data with the current code i have which uses olefile to extract text from a ppt file

```
import olefile

ole = olefile.OleFileIO(r'C:\sampleppt.ppt')

print(ole.listdir())
data = ole.openstream('PowerPoint Document').read()
print(data)
ole.close()
```

How do I use olefile properly to extract the text from ppt files?

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS Homebrew users: install Apache Tika (`brew install tika`)
I think it also supports other OSs.

The command-line interface works like this:

```
tika --text something.ppt > something.txt
```

And to use it inside python script:

```
import os
os.system("tika --text temp.ppt > temp.txt")
```

You will be able to do it and that is the only solution I have so far.